# label displaying null if string not giving any value .... want to display nothing if no value given by string

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

i am using label to display data from various string but if string is not giving any value i want to display nothing in label but hare in below code it is displaying "null" if no value is given by sting.
i don't want to display null in label .... how can i solve it.

```
where_do_you_hurt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@",appdelegate.hurt_head,appdelegate.hurt_Arm,
                          appdelegate.hurt_leg,appdelegate.hurt_chest,appdelegate.hurt_Back];
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For each value that you don't want to have `(null)` printed, you need to provide an empty string if the value is `nil`. You can do so like this:

```
foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (obj ? obj : @"")];
```

The `obj ? obj : @""` means: if the object is not nil (`obj ?`) then pass the object (`obj`), otherwise pass the empty string (`: @""`).

An alternative would be use to a mutable string and then do:

```
if (obj) {
    [foo appendFormat:@"%@", obj];
}
```

Comment: You can also shorten it to `obj ?: @""`

Comment: For my 

NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@°F",(temp ? temp : @" ")];

I get "°F" instead of empty. Any quick fix? Thanks.

Comment: @MPaulo: Think about it: the format is always `@"%@°F"`, no matter which value `temp` has. You only change what you're passing as an _argument_ to the format. One solution would be: `temp = temp ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@°F", temp] : @"";`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want "null" to appear for nil objects, then you need to supply an empty string instead:

```
where_do_you_hurt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"%@,%@,%@,%@",
                          appdelegate.hurt_head ? appdelegate.hurt_head : @"",
                          appdelegate.hurt_Arm ? appdelegate.hurt_Arm : @"",
                          appdelegate.hurt_leg ? appdelegate.hurt_leg : @"",
                          appdelegate.hurt_chest ? appdelegate.hurt_chest : @"",
                          appdelegate.hurt_Back ? appdelegate.hurt_Back : @""];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the macro that I use for safe string instead of getting "(null)" string on a UILabel for example:

```
#define SafeString(STRING) ([STRING length] == 0 ? @"" : STRING)

NSLog(@"%@", member.name); // prints (null) on UILabel
```

with macro:

```
NSLog(@"%@", SafeString(member.name)); // prints empty string on UILabel
```

nice and clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

About `NSString`...  `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nil]` will log as `(null)`

You could put your text together incrementally, testing for nil values.

OR

You could initialize those 4 properties in your appdelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.hurt_head = [NSString string];
    self.hurt_Arm = [NSString string];
    self.hurt_leg = [NSString string];
    self.hurt_chest = [NSString string];
    self.hurt_back = [NSString string];
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can check for null using

if (title == (id)[NSNull null] || title.length == 0 ) title = @"Something";

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. Its not as compact as the others, but its more readable I feel (which is always most important to me).

It also has the benefit of removing trailing whitespaces from the beginning and the end.

```
// Remove any nulls from the first or last name
firstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (firstName ? firstName : @"")];
lastName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (lastName ? lastName : @"")];

// Concat the strings
fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];

// Remove any trailing whitespace
fullName = NSString *newString = [oldString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0):

import these file directly in your project and use rMtext instead of text property.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UILabel (NullHandling)
@property(nonatomic,copy)   NSString       *rMtext; 
@end

#import "UILabel+NullHandling.h"
#import <objc/message.h>

@implementation UILabel (NullHandling)
-(void)setRMtext:(NSString *)text {

if(text!=nil){
text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(null)" withString:@""];
    self.text=text;     
  }
}
-(NSString *)rMtext {

    return self.text; 
}
@end
```